# How do you manipulate an inserted object in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Insert an object in sheets (ex: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(String,Integer,Integer)):

```
var obj = sheet.insert{ObjectType}(args.);
```

You can call your charts in sheets:

```
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().{params}.build;
```

And can call objects in docs:

```
docs.getBody().findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.{object type}, null);
```

What's the equivalent for finding objects in sheets, i.e. is there a gsheets dom model like there is  for docs? or are non-chart objects inaccessible through gAppscript?

```
//get objects in sheet    
var obj2 = sheet.getObject()[0]
//error, method doesn't exist
//
//get objects near a range
var obj3 = sheet.getRange(x,y).getObject()
//error
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but data in Sheets isn't organized the same way it is in Docs. What kind of "objects" are you trying to find? I think you should be able to retrieve and manipulate most anything with a combination of [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)), [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), and setValues.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(String,Integer,Integer)

Once inserted, can you programatically manipulate it from google appsscript

Comment: Ah, so... you mean images. The short answer, then, is that you don't manipulate or delete them. There's a four year old issue raised [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=64) about deleting images, and as of last week, there's still no way to do that programmatically. The consensus there is that you ought to use the =IMAGE() equation if possible. I just tried it out and it works well; the only constraint is that the image must be bounded by a cell.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that link, although I did specifically intend on a programmatic method for various reasons which weren't disclosed in the original question. As a sidepoint, there are issues with your recommended method as well, such as, it can only display a publicly available url, there are loads of SE convos on that.

Comment: Indeed, it's imperfect, but as far as I know, it's the best we've got right now.