# Reposition images(s) in google spreadsheet using script (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had success with inserting images into a google spreadsheet...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

sheet.insertImage("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", 1, 1, 10, 10);
```

But is there any way to work with the images once they have been inserted? 
For instance is there a way to reposition them? Delete them? Resize them. Etc.

(ultimately I want to reposition them)

Btw, the images get inserted via url. Is the link to the url retained, or does it now reside as an object within the spreadsheet? 
I can't seem to find a way to view the image properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184693/how-do-you-manipulate-an-inserted-object-in-google-sheets/27193584#27193584) from a few days ago. Essentially, you can't programmatically delete or manipulate images after you insert them. You can, however, insert the =IMAGE() formula into a cell and delete or modify that.

Comment: This is a viable workaround. It requires a bit of effort to get the valid URLs of images stored in Google Drive, but the result is adequate. Plus I actually prefer that this method handles the images on the sheet level as opposed to programmatically. So THANK YOU very much for your help.

Comment: @5th4x4, but how to get a valid URL of image stored in google drive?

Comment: lol @Ivan Gusev ... you do realize that this question was originally posted almost 4 yrs ago, right :P  So I would need to check my files for the notes from that time (hopefully later today I'll be able to do that for you). But even so, 4 yrs is a long time in Google's world, and I'm guessing that they've made some changes to the way they do things since that time. Best bet in the meantime is to try actually Googling your question. My guess is that you'll likely get a quicker (and more current) response that way. Try it, and then let me know if you still need me to check my notes. Good luck!

Comment: @5th4x4, big thanks for quick reply, very appreciate it. I can't agree about 4 yrs. But after many hours of googling and trying i have solved my need.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, October of 2018, there are ways to manipulate images in sheet. It seems it's at experimental stages and documentation is not fully done yet. The working code for resizing and deleting is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602177/deleting-images-in-google-sheet-via-script-error/52602450#52602450) (again, there is no official documentation). This answer's purpose is to make sure that those that reached here will have a more timely answer than the accepted one in 2014.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var imgLnk = 'link of the image';
sheet.insertImage(imgLnk, 2, 2); //This insert image at B2
var img = sheet.getImages()[0]; //Assuming there is only 1 image in the sheet
img.setAnchorCell('N1');
```

The last line `img.setAnchorCell` may not work for you. It's known that experimental feature like this work differently for different people. The case proven is function `delete()` use to delete image does not work the same way for different people.

Comment: I think this would be better fitted as a comment under the the question and/or under the accepted answer. Like you said, "..this does not answer the question..".

Comment: For the purpose of those searching for answer, a comment in an answer that contradict the accepted answer would not have the sufficient validity for them to move on to a productive path. I think the benefit of getting this as an answer to the community is far more than getting the right technicality of classification of it. It would say the accepted answer is no longer correct in an obvious and meaningful way.

Comment: The contents of your 'answer' are useful and provide information for someone looking at the question/answers now. However, it is still not an answer and should not be mistaken for one. I see no problem by re-purposing your 'answer' as a comment. Alternatively, you could modify it so that it actually answers the question (albeit from a different -more up to date- standpoint) and by doing so you could also provide the useful information as a background context. As it stands now, IMHO this is not answer but a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21016481)

Comment: I do not critique or request clarification. I provide addition information and code that could achieve the goal stated in the question. The fact that the functionality is experimental does not change the fact that my answer is the best information at the moment to get to the goal of the question.

Comment: @Anand Nimje This answer is much better than the accepted answer, why not delete that?

Answer (score 0):

There is now a `.remove()` method for `OverGridImage` objects: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image