# Deleting images in Google sheet via script error

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I probably will get downvoted for this but I can't do anything else. I searched, read and tried SOOOO many things. I am new at both Javascript and Google platform.

I have this piece of code that keeps telling me

> "Missing name after . operation".

Even though `.delete` and `.getAltTextTitle` are both shown in autocomplete suggestion

```
  var images = sheet.getImages();
  var img = images[0];
  Logger.log(img.getAltTextTitle()); //This is fine
  img.delete(); //This throw error
```

In the meanwhile, I have this piece of code working totally fine. I don't know what to do. They look the same to me.

```
  var img = sheet.getImages()[0];
  var imgH = img.getHeight();
  var imgW = img.getWidth();
  var maxW = 700;
  var newImgH = Math.round(imgH*(maxW/imgW));
  img.setWidth(maxW);
  img.setHeight(newImgH);
```

Unrelated topic, where do I get the documentation for `sheet.getImages()` because I just couldn't find it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- You want to delete the image on Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

If my understand is correct, I think that `delete()` might be new method which will be added for Spreadsheet in the near future. So the document is not updated and it might not complete yet. But from the error message, if you want to use the current `delete()` method, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
var images = sheet.getImages();
var img = images[0];
img["delete"](); // this one
```

#### Note:

- I think that the detail infomation might be added to [this document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).
- In my environment, I could confirm that the image can be deleted by `img["delete"]()`. I think that this is one of new methods.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Update at 2018 October 13:

Now in order to delete the image, the following method can be used. This was confirmed at 2018 October 13.

```
var images = sheet.getImages();
var img = images[0];
img.remove(); // Here
```

### Update at 2018 October 31:

[This was officially released at October 30, 2018.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/)

You can see the document at [Class OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image).

Comment: This works. It seems that my problem really about not understanding a new feature. I am so glad that's in essence it's not a repeated question.

Comment: @Tam Le I'm glad your issue was solved. Also it was found that users who can already use the method of ``delete()`` are existing. I think that it might depend on the account and/or region. But from this situation, also in your and my environment, we might get to be able to use the complete methods in the near future.

Comment: `img["delete"]();` is not working now. Just an update.

Comment: @Tam Le Thank you for your additional information. I could also confirm the same situation. When I used this ``var image = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getImages()[0]; for (var i in image) Logger.log(i)``, in the current stage, the delete method cannot be found. The method might be modified.

Comment: Usually, `delete` is mean to remove property in an object in Javascript. I also tried way to remove element from an array but it would not remove existing image in the sheet ( it might when refresh the sheet but that's not good enough).  Image class should have it own method

Comment: How can we specify the sheet name instead of using getActiveSheet() ?

Comment: @shadowz1337 I'm sorry I cannot understand about your situation from your comment.

Comment: It was a pretty straight forward / simple question? Anyway found my answer.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet Name Here");

Comment: @shadowz1337 I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I apologize for my poor skill.